# TypeScript Can't Find Prisma Client Model Types

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I have a model called User.

When I generate the Prisma client, I can see that there are lots of types generated for that model automatically. I can see them in the client file.

But Typescript can only find one of the types: UserScalarFieldEnum.

UserSelect returns undefined.

All other such types I can see in the client return undefined.

I'm on Windows 11. I've tried regenerating the client several times. I've even tried recreating the entire thing from scratch.

Even when I followed a Typescript + Prisma setup tutorial from the Prisma website, I still saw this problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is what my model looks like:

```
model User {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String  @unique
  name  String?
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that only `UserScalarFieldEnum` can be found by TypeScript? Are you using latest version of prisma? If your repository is open source then sharing its link would also be helpful

Comment: Make sure you're in a type context. If you're not, you won't get the autocomplete. Basically make sure that what you're typing is TS and not JS.